# socket.io server work fine in local host but doesn't work on server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

iam new in node.js and socket.io
i developing sample socket.io project and i want passing argument to connection event and cordova app that connect to socket.io server

its work fine in local host but error in server
i should add it, after connection event successful, supposed to post request well

i tried many solution but dosnt work

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://serverip/socket.io/socket.io.js

GET http://serverip:3000/socket.io/?username=0912101&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lg_3duf net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT socket.io.js

on server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var rest = require('restler');
var serverpath = 'http://serverip';
var userconnectiondata =
    {
        username: '',
        cred: '',
        socketid: ''
    }
var connectionlist = [];
server.listen(3000);

console.log("server running");

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



io.use(function (socket, next) {


    var userconnectiondata =
        {
            username: socket.handshake.query.username,
            cred: socket.handshake.query.cred,
            socketid: socket.id
        }
    console.log('con %s', socket.id);


    connectionlist.push(userconnectiondata);

    var jsonData = {
        username: userconnectiondata.username,
        SocketID: userconnectiondata.socketid
    };

    rest.postJson(serverpath + '/Chat/UpdateSocketId', jsonData).on('complete', function (data, response) {
       // handle response
    });



    next();
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; connectionlist.length; i++) {

            if (connectionlist[i].socketid == socket.id) {
                connectionlist.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }

        }

        console.log('discon %s', socket.id);
    });


});
```

in client

```
 <script src="http://serverip/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

 var temp = "username=0912101" ;
  socket = io("http://serverip:3000", {
    query: temp
     });
```

i appreciate any help my firends